# django_markdown editor is not showing up in Django 1.10?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I am using Django 1.10 with python 3.4. Here are the settings as recommended by [django_markdown github page](https://github.com/klen/django_markdown)

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_markdown',
    'blog',
]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('^markdown/', include( 'django_markdown.urls')),
]
```

models.py

```
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #..
    content = MarkdownField()
```

Inside the admin text editor looks like this:

[image]

Comment: how you are loading `form`? show your `forms.py` file

Comment: I am loading this from models.py not from forms.py

Comment: @Shri Did you see any problem with the code ?

Comment: check `Admin override` section in doc. I am not sure but it may help.

Comment: But, It works perfectly with Django 1.8 with same configuration but not with Django 1.10.